# Only specific users timing out

Tags: errors

First-time asker here. Grateful for any help!

I have a user who is timing out every time they try to edit a page in the Divi builder.
Here is what I know:

- My user and other users are not timing out, however, some other users ARE timing out.
- When I create a new user for this person, it still is timing out.
- This began after we pushed from the staging server to production via GoDaddy.
- All users still work on staging.
- the timing out occurs with the user on my machine as well, which then prevents even the front-end website from loading for a period of time afterward.

We've tried clearing website data, disabling firewall, etc... Any ideas!?

Comment: Hey Ben, welcome! :) Do you get any particular error when this happens or is it a white screen?

Comment: Thanks! 
The error was "This site can't be reached. domain.com took too long to respond."

Comment: This is not necessarily the ideal or true solution, but have you tried increasing the PHP timeout? Does that fix it?

Comment: Haven't tried that, although I do have a support inquiry in with GoDaddy. Seems like there may be something wrong with the server, right? I actually downloaded a backup of the site today to run locally and had to fix some quotation marks in the WP-config folder in order to get the admin to start on Local. I wonder if that is related...